# Solve $\sin(4x) = \sin(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

Solve $\sin(4x) = \sin(x)$ for $0 < x < 180$

and solve $\tan(4x) = \tan(x)$ for $0 < x < 2 \pi$

I think you have to use the addition formulas however I keep on getting stuck on the working so I don't know if I have simply made a mistake or if I'm approaching the question wrong.
Thanks

Comment: What did you try? Where are you struggling?

Comment: I have tried using the sine addition formula however I keep on getting stuck because I have both sine and cosine multiplying each other and can't factor them apart...

Comment: @AlexJones When is the sine of two angles equal?

Comment: @Workaholic when those two angles are the same? I know this must be something really stupid but I just don't see it...

Comment: @Workaholic, asking too many questions.

Comment: @abel Hahaha :-)

Comment: @AlexJones "When those two angles are the same", that's one case, but it's not the only one. Draw the unit circle, hopefully things will get clearer then.

Comment: @Workaholic, good to see you. hope everything is going well.

Comment: @Workaholic ok yeah I was being really thick. Thanks, I understand it now

Comment: @abel Thanks, things aren't going as I hope but I'm alright for now. Hope everything is going well for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the first problem:

$$
\sin 4x = \sin x \qquad 0 < x < \pi
$$

Rather than using the addition formula for sine, consider the geometric interpretation of the sine function, being the height of a point on the circumference of the unit circle.  This yields

$$
\sin x = \sin (\pi - x) = \sin (x + 2\pi) = \sin (3\pi-x) = \cdots
$$

Since $0 < x < \pi$, we need go no further (the next term would be $\sin (x+4\pi)$).  So you can now solve

$$
4x = \pi - x
$$
$$
4x = x + 2\pi
$$
$$
4x = 3\pi - x
$$

for three different values of $x$, and those will be your solutions.  (Be sure that the domain of solutions really is $0 < x < \pi$, for otherwise $0$ and $\pi$ are also solutions.)

See if you can apply the same kind of thinking for the second problem.